# Overflow Menu on item click for Popup Menu

Tags: android

I am working on android project and I am wanting to do so something but I can't find how to do it. I've called it an Overflow Menu but I am not sure if that's the correct name.

Basically, what I am trying to do, when the user clicks certain GUI element a popup menu is shown, when the user selects a certain menu item, an extra menu is shown with some more menu items.

There should be some sort of indication to show that there is a some more menu items for a particular menu item.

Below is the XML that I have tried to define the menu but it only shows the second menu item not the host menu item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/dbTable_mnu"
        android:title="Select Rows">
        <item android:id="@+id/test"
            android:title="Test">
        </item>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested submenus are defined using the <menu> tag inside an <item> block.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/dbTable_mnu" android:title="Select Rows">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/test" android:title="Test" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

See [Menu Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) on the Android Developers site for more information.